# Understanding dual (noncommutative) modules / vector spaces functorially

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra, monoidal-categories

For vector spaces over a fixed field $\Bbbk$, there's a natural transformation from the identity functor to the double dual functor. I think here's a way to construct it. Start from the identity arrow $1_{V^\ast}$. The counit of the tensor-hom adjunction sends it to $\mathrm{eval}_V:V^\ast \otimes V\rightarrow \Bbbk$ which is defined by $\mathrm{eval}(m):f\mapsto f(m)$. Now since $\otimes $ is symmetric for vector spaces, we can identify the evaluation natural with the evaluation on $M\otimes M^\ast$, defined in the same manner. Now if we take the adjunct of this map along the *unit* of adjunction, we get a map $$\phi_V:V\rightarrow \mathsf{hom}(V^\ast,\Bbbk)=V^{\ast\ast}$$ defined by $$\phi_V(v):f\mapsto f(v)$$

Now, for a left module $M$ over a noncummutative ring $R$, we still define $M^\ast=\mathsf{hom}(M,R)$ and find it is a *right* $R$-module. We still use the map $\phi_M(m):f\mapsto f(m)$. However, the tensor product is no longer symmetric, so...

How to get $\phi:1\Rightarrow (-)^{\ast\ast}$ from the tensor hom adjunction for modules over noncommutative rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the correct hom–tensor adjunction. Recall that, for rings $R, S, T$, an $(R, S)$-bimodule $M$, $(S, T)$-bimodule $N$, and $(R, T)$-bimodule $P$, we have:
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{(R, T)} (M \otimes_S N, P) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{(R, S)} (M, \mathrm{Hom}_{(\mathbb{Z}, T)} (N, P))$$
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{(R, T)} (M \otimes_S N, P) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{(S, T)} (N, \mathrm{Hom}_{(R, \mathbb{Z})} (M, P))$$
In particular, if we take $R = T$, $S = \mathbb{Z}$, and $P = R$, we get
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{(R, \mathbb{Z})} (M, \mathrm{Hom}_{(\mathbb{Z}, R)} (N, R)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{(\mathbb{Z}, R)} (N, \mathrm{Hom}_{(R, \mathbb{Z})} (M, R))$$
and taking $N = \mathrm{Hom}_{(R, \mathbb{Z})} (M, R)$, this yields a natural $(R, \mathbb{Z})$-bimodule homomorphism
$$M \to \mathrm{Hom}_{(\mathbb{Z}, R)} (\mathrm{Hom}_{(R, \mathbb{Z})} (M, R), R)$$
as desired. Note that we use two different hom functors here!

Of course, we can do all this in the non-additive / many-object setting as well, which leads to the notion of Isbell conjugation.

Comment: In the first two isos, shouldn't $\mathsf{Hom}_{(\mathbb Z,T)},\mathsf{Hom}_{(R,\mathbb Z)}$ switch lines?

Comment: No. Check the types yourself.

Comment: But if $\mathsf{Hom}_{(\mathbb Z,T)}$ should really be in the first line, then isn't it a functor $_R\mathsf{Mod}_T\longrightarrow _R\mathsf{Mod}_S$? How does that settle with the notation? I mean isn't the first iso saying we have an adjunction $-\otimes _S N\dashv \mathsf{Hom}_{(\mathbb Z,T)}(N,-)$?

Comment: But $P$ is an $(R,T)$ bimodule, not an $(S,T)$ bimodule, so how is $\mathrm{Hom}_{(\mathbb{Z}, T)} (N, P)$ even defined?

Comment: $\mathrm{Hom}_{(\mathbb{Z}, T)} (N, -)$ is a functor from $(R, T)$-bimodules to $(R, S)$-bimodules, indeed. The left $R$-action comes from the given $(R, T)$-bimodule and the right $S$-action comes from the left (!) $S$-action on $N$.

Comment: Confusing stuff! thanks for the answer, I'll try to work with these things a bit.